# How does the get method for ArrayLists work?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am curious as to what the actual code is for the get method that is used in arraylists.
Ex.
arrayList.get(i)

I want to know what the actual code is that get is using. 
If no one knows the answer to this question then what would be an alternative way to return an element from an arrayList?

Additionally, this is all in java.

Thanks,
Dio

Comment: [`ArrayList` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java?av=f)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Also, Grepcode is a website where they list source code for many languages and frameworks, Google will find source code quickly if you put "grepcode" in the search query.

Here's the code for [ArrayList.get():](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.get%28int%29)

```
   public E get(int index) {
         rangeCheck(index);
         return elementData(index);
   }
```

Comment: What exactly is elementData? I have never seen it before

Comment: @Dio The link is right there. Follow it.

Comment: I have followed it, searched around it, and I don't understand it. I have never looked at source code before since I have only been coding for five months. Thus, I'm not understanding what are probably simple concepts.

Comment: Ask it then as another question.  In particular, what precisely don't you understand?